# Як сказати українською "сослуживец"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Який український відповідник слова "сослуживец"?

Варіанти, які пропонують [словники на r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on): *співпрацівник, співробітник, однослуживець, супрацівник, товариш по службі.*

Якому з цих (або інших) варіантів варто надавати перевагу?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Запитання, які не демонструють спроби автора самостійно відповісти на нього, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour](https://goo.gl/XbjRge), [How to Ask](https://goo.gl/KuCfff) а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](https://goo.gl/wnuKFr). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть edit у лівому нижньому куті під запитанням. Ще раз, ласкаво просимо і дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: @bytebuster, нагадую, що «low research effort» не є причиною закриття питання.

Comment: @Sasha, згоден, не є формальним «приводом». Але є — *першопричиною*. Саме відсутність бажання автора запитання бодай трошки дослідити проблему найчастіше призводить до усіх основних причин закриття. Про це ж свідчить відсутність спроби автора вчасно виправити запитання після того, як йому було вказано на це. Але хороша новина — у нас на сайті є багато prominent users, хто можуть докласти свого часу, сил та натхнення, аби виправити запитання і зупинити хвилю мінусів, яку вже почав отримувати новий дописувач.

Comment: @bytebuster Можна лише додати якусь дрібку необхідної/корисної інформації, якої немає в питанні, редагуючи його. Додавати research effort виходить за межі стандартного редагування - це обов'язок людини, котра ставить питання.

Comment: @improbable я запропонувала "дрібку інформації" (і додатковий тег) до запитання вчора. Не вистачає ще одного голосу аби схвалити цей варіант.

Answer (score 2):

Якщо довіряти [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/), то російське *сослуживец* можна перекласти як ***"співпрацівник"***, ***"співробітник"*** чи ***"колега"***.

*[Сocлyживeц](http://ozhegov.textologia.ru/definit/sosluzhivec/?q=742&n=204578)* - це:

> Чeлoвeк, кoтopый cлyжит вмecтe c кeм-нибyдь, paбoтaeт c кeм-нибyдь в
>   oднoм yчpeждeнии. *Mы c ним cocлyживцы. Бывшиe cocлyживцы.*

Тобто мова йде про когось, хто служить чи працює разом з кимось.

СУМ-11 подає декілька слів з подібним значенням. ***[Співпрацівник](http://sum.in.ua/s/spivpracivnyk)***:

> Той, хто займається якою-небудь діяльністю, працює разом із кимсь.

***[Співробітник](http://sum.in.ua/s/spivrobitnyk)***:

> 1. Той, хто працює разом із ким-небудь, допомагає йому в якійсь справі.

Слово *співробітник* має також друге значення, безвідносне до інших працівників:

> 2. Особа, що працює в якійсь установі; службовець. || Особа, що бере участь як автор у роботі періодичного чи багатотомного видання.
>      Науковий співробітник — посада працівника науково-дослідної установи,
>      а також особа, що займає цю посаду.

Окрім цього, є слово ***[колега](http://sum.in.ua/s/kolegha)***, яке має ширше значення, ніж співпрацівник та співробітник:

> Товариш за фахом, місцем праці, за навчанням у вищій школі тощо.

Слів *однослуживець*, *супрацівник* СУМ-11 не містить.

Фраза *товариш по службі* [не надто подобається](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-39030096) проф. Пономареву:

> Віктор Пилипенко хоче знати, як відтворити українською мовою російське слово *сослуживець* [sic].
>
> Калька *співслужбовець*, на думку читача, дуже неоковирна. Це справді не дуже вдала калька, але пропонований словниками вислів *товариш по службі* теж не ліпший.

Своїх варіантів перекладу проф. Пономарів не пропонує.

До речі, в ["Уроках державної мови"](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/129.htm) Б. Рогози та посібнику ["Чи правильно ми говоримо"](http://chak-chy-pravylno-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/r#robitnyk-pratsivnyk-spivrobitnyk) Є. Чак є детальні роз'яснення відмінностей між словами *робітник, працівник, співробітник*.

За цими роз'ясненнями *працівник* має ширше значення ніж *робітник*, адже означає того, хто трудиться, незалежно від сфери його діяльності. *Робітник* же часто означає того, хто працює на промисловому підприємстві. З огляду на це, слово ***співпрацівник*** є цілком доречним, коли говоримо про когось, хто працює з кимось взагалі (безвідносно до галузі праці).

Однак і ***співробітник*** можна вживати в цьому значенні (див. тлумачення 1 з СУМ-11 вище). Хоча частіше це слово використовують все-таки як компонент назви посади (*науковий співробітник*, *співробітник районної газети*).

Що ж до ***колеги***, то думаю, з цим словом важко помилитися - будь-який *сослуживец* є *колегою*. Хоча, звісно, не всі *колеги* є *сослуживцами*, адже слово *колеги* не завжди позначає тих, хто працює разом.

Answer (score 2):

**Колега (колежанка)** і **побратим**

Служба буває на [державних посадах](https://protocol.ua/ua/pro_dergavnu_slugbu_vid_10_12_2015_889_viii_stattya_6/) або [військовою](http://kamadm.gov.ua/press-tsentr/item/6397-viiskova-sluzhba-za-kontraktom-vymohy-pilhy-ta-vakansii). Український відповідник залежатиме від контексту.

1. [Колега](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8) ([колежанка](https://slova.com.ua/word/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)) (лат. collega) — товариш за фахом, місцем праці, за навчанням у вищій школі тощо. Особа тієї самої професії.
2. [Побратим](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC) — соратник по якій-небудь діяльності, сподвижник; [названий брат](http://sum.in.ua/s/pobratym); товариш по боротьбі, битві, боях.

Answer (score -1):

Співслуживець саме нормально)це моя думка

Comment: Дякуємо за відповідь. Але в нас не прийнято писати відповіді, що базуються лише на інтуїції. Чи могли б Ви (щоб ідеально) навести приклади реального вживання цього слова десь (хоча я не бачу його в жодних словниках, але я бачу, що його знаходять [Google](//google.com/search?q=співслуживець), [Google Книги](//google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=співслуживець) й [ГРАК-11](http://parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac11&queryselector=wordrow&word=співслуживе?ц.*)) або (хоча б) спробувати якось аргументувати.